# How to use the history to update the pagination bar with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

These are my routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/pages" component={Pages} />
    <Route path="/page/:page(\d+)" component={Pages} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This is the component I have trouble with:

```
class Pages extends React.Component {
  buildHref = href => `/page/${href}`;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.history.push(this.props.match.url);
  }

  handlePageChange = page => {
    this.props.history.push(`/page/${page.selected + 1}`);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactPaginate
          previousLabel="<"
          nextLabel=">"
          pageCount={10}
          pageRangeDisplayed={10}
          onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
          initialPage={parseInt(this.props.match.params.page - 1, 0)}
          containerClassName={"pagination"}
          activeClassName={"active"}
          hrefBuilder={this.buildHref}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Pages);
```

Code:

[image: here]

When I go back using the browser's history the url updates but the pagination bar doesn't change. The active class remains on the same element. What is the best way to rerender the pagination bar with the correct active page number in this case?

Also going back it will show /page/NaN at one point, and after that it is not possible to go forward.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you minusing 1 from the initial page selection:

`initialPage={parseInt(this.props.match.params.page - 1, 0)}`

You want the pagination component to show the same number as the url.

so `initialPage={parseInt(this.props.match.params.page, 0)}` should work fine

---

Additionally why have:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.history.push(this.props.match.url);
  }
```

You shouldn't need that and it might be messing with your pagination updating

Comment: -1 is because if there is for example a /page/6 in the url and I reload the page, it will make the page 7 active. And without componentDidMount I can't access the /pages at all, it will redirect to /page/NaN